# Automate drop down using Page factory model

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Page factory model in my project, thus:

```
public class Loginsingup {
  WebDriver driver;
  public Loginsingup(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver; PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
  }

  @FindBy(id="FirstName") WebElement fname;
}
```

How I can identify drop down value in page factory. I know another way :

```
Select country = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedCountryID")));    
country.selectByVisibleText("UNITED STATES");
```

but how to do it in page factory. I have created separate Object Repository package for all pages and created another package for test cases.

I have saved all java classes in the object repository. But element like drop down what I have to write in java class and how I can access it in test cases.

Comment: Can you explain (or link to an explanation of) what you mean by Page factory model? I use page factories and it doesn't change how web driver elements are used or found, so my understanding of the model is different to yours.

Comment: Hi Paul, Here is sample code for java class : Hi Paul, here is sample sample java class file that I have used: public class Loginsingup {
  WebDriver driver;
  public Loginsingup(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);                           }  
  @FindBy(id="FirstName")
    WebElement fname;

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple wrapper accessor around the WebElement accessor, like this:

```
@FindBy(id="SelectedCountryID") WebElement countryDropdown;

public Select getCountrySelect() {
  return new Select(countryDropdown);
}
```

You can add helpful mutators too, like this (I've invented the `Country` class: you might prefer to pass IDs around, or something else):

```
public void setCountry(Country country) {
  getCountrySelect().selectByValue(country.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Page Factory select drop down the given code will work:

```
@FindBy(id="FirstName") WebElement fname;

Select dropdown = new Select(fname);  
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("UNITED STATES");
```